# Cambiar la fuente a un DatePicker

Tags: swift, xcode

Llevo días buscando y no consigo cambiar la fuente de un control tipo Datepicker.

Puedo cambiar el color mediante:

> datePicker.tintColor = UIColor.blue

Pero no encuentro como cambiar la fuente y su tamaño.

Answer (score 0):

Ha una pregunta realizada en Stack Overflow en ingles que trata tu problema, espero que te sirva. Saludos

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844675/custom-ios-uidatepicker-using-uiappearance

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Por lo que veo Apple no da las herramientas para personalizar la fuente de un UIDatePicker y, haciendo las mil y una, lo consigues hacer pero...  al final parece que corres el riesgo de que rechacen la APP.

Comment: Eso he leído en algunos sitios, que no dan las herramientas para la personalización.

Comment: @MarioGuiber Si bien es cierto que esa respuesta puede responder a la pregunta, sería bueno que coloque la parte mas relevante del código que responde a la pregunta, ya que si por alguna razón el link de la respuesta que colocó es eliminado, otros usuarios no tendrán acceso a esa respuesta si tienen la misma duda.